# Why Use Two Different Tests for Existence of Linear Regression: Value of $R^2$ vs $H_0$: slope $= 0$

Tags: regression, correlation

I am trying to understand better the tests used to determine the existence of a linear relation between two variables $X$,$Y$.  AFAIK, one way of testing the strength of any linear relationship is by computing $R^2$, where $R$ is the correlation coefficient; this measures the extend to which $X$ determines $Y$, i.e., the extend to which the value of $X$ contributes to the value of $Y$.
                   But then there is a second test, and I am confused as to how it relates to the one above. In this other test, we do a hypothesis test for the slope of the regression line $Y= m X+b$  , with $ H_0: m=0, H_A: m \neq 0 $.

Are both these tests necessary, or is one used to corroborate the other?  Are there situations where one test is preferable to the other?

Comment: Merely computing $R^2$ is not a test. Both $R^2$ and significance of the slope are not enough to determine whether the linear relationship exists. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe's_quartet for example.

Comment: @mpiktas: Thank you, is there something else I can do to test the existence of a linear relationship other than plotting the values of y against those of x?

Comment: You can do lots of things. Many approaches are described in this site and in general literature. The most suitable approach depends on the particular problem you want to solve. Determining that relationship is exactly linear is a quite rare problem, since it is also very difficult. Please add more details on what are you actually trying to solve.